# Is it necessary to replace a hot tub pump if its seal has a leak?

Tags: leak, pump, hot-tub

I have a hot tub that is leaking from the pump seal (this was diagnosed by a hot tub tech).  They gave me a quote for replacing the pump, which unfortunately is going to require some re-plumbing of the tub since it is an older tub and they apparently don't make/use this specific pump anymore.

However, after a bit of googling it seems that it would be more practical to just replace the pump seal itself rather than the entire pump.  Is there some other reason for why I might have to replace the entire pump in this situation?

Comment: If the electronics/windings for the motor portion aren't comprised you should be about to rebuild the pump with just replacing seals. Some motors and/or pumps are designed to not allow rebuilds in which case you'd need to replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, turns out that I was able to replace the pump seal and now everything is working fine.  Pretty crazy to think that the hot tub service company was going to charge $1000 for the new pump & plumbing vs. the